# Angular 2: Toggle sidenav from different Component

Tags: angular, material-design, angular2-services

I have a sidenav that I would like to open from a different component. I created a service for this, since it's not a parent/child relation, but I keep getting the nav back as undefined. What am I doing wrong?

This is the service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {MdSidenav, MdSidenavToggleResult} from "@angular/material";

@Injectable()
export class SidenavService {
  private sidenav: MdSidenav;

  public setSidenav(sidenav: MdSidenav) {
    this.sidenav = sidenav;
  }

  public open(): Promise<MdSidenavToggleResult> {
    return this.sidenav.open();
  }

  public toggle(isOpen?: boolean): Promise<MdSidenavToggleResult> {
    return this.sidenav.toggle(isOpen);
  }
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

this is html of InstellingenComponent with the sidenav (I deleted some of the content so It's more readable):

```
<md-sidenav #sidenav align="end" mode="side" opened="true">
  <div>
    <h3>Weergave aanpasssen</h3>
    <section class="instellingen">
             <h3>Kleuren</h3>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
  </md-sidenav>
```

In another component I have:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      }

  public toggleSidenav() {
    this.sidenavService
      .toggle()
      .then(() => {
      });
  } }
```

and the following html:

```
    <button md-icon-button (click)="toggleSidenav()" class="button">
<md-icon>settings</md-icon></button>
```

Comment: Are  you setting the reference to the side nav using the `setSidenav` function? If so, can you please post that portion of the code?

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the `InstellingenComponent.ts` file?

Comment: hmmm..I don't have anything relateble in the InstellingenComponent.ts... did I forget something?

Comment: The sidenav service needs a reference to the side nav in your application so that it can open/close it. The InstellingenComponent component needs to do this since this is the component that has the sidenav. Please refer my answer and see if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a reference to the sidenav in your sidenav service so that the service can open/close the sidenav. Otherwise, it will always be `undefined`

In order to do this, open the `InstellingenComponent.ts` file (the component whose template has the side nav component), and make the following changes:

Add this line of code to get a reference to the side nav component in the template (Add this preferably at the top, just below the `export class InstellingenComponent` statement)
`@ViewChild('sidenav') public sidenav: MdSidenav;`

Inside your constructor, inject the SidenavService like below (note, add it to the ones that you already might have)

```
  public constructor(
    private sidenavService: SidenavService
  )
```

Make sure the class implements `OnInit` like below.
`export class InstellingenComponent implements OnInit`

Finally, in your `ngOnInit()` function (Add new if not already present), set the reference to the sidenav like this:

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sidenavService
      .setSidenav(this.sidenav);
  }
```

Comment: Aha! That worked ! Thank you for your help. I'm finding Angular pretty difficult, but not giving up :)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody else happens to be in the same boat:

```
import {MdSidenav, MdSidenavToggleResult} from "@angular/material";
```

should be:

```
import {MdSidenav, MdDrawerToggleResult} from "@angular/material";
```

Don't forget to change it inside the promises also.

I'm using

```
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10"
```

By the way, the answer from @CodeWarrior is correct. It helped me too.

Answer (score 0):

In the below service toggle function this.sidenav is undefined.

```
 public toggle(isOpen?: boolean): Promise<MdSidenavToggleResult> {
    return this.sidenav.toggle(isOpen);
  }
```